# Do we use the word "disjoint" as a noun?

Tags: nouns

I've looked up in the dictionary and didn't find a noun form of the word *disjoint*.
What is the word if I want to mean the fact that 2 things are disjointed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Disjointedness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disjointedness) is the noun form of disjoint, and means the quality of being disjoint. If you're asking for a noun that applies to objects that are themselves disjoint, I think you're out of luck, and *disjoint things* is as close as you can get.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize it can be converted first to `disjointed`, but is there any difference between `disjoint` and `disjointed`? I think `disjoint` can be used as an adjective itself

Comment: I don't perceive a difference between *disjoint* and *disjointed*. Some dictionaries seem to say that the adjective *disjoint* is now only used in mathematics and related fields, and *disjointed* is the correct adjective for other uses. But the noun is *disjointedness* for both adjectives.

Comment: Actually I use it in something related to maths. I use it to mean two shapes don't intersect.

Answer (score 0):

Disjointed is the adjective used to describe something that is lacking a coherent sequence or connection.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disjointed

Comment: In reply to the comment on the below answer. Disjoint as an adjective: An element can be disjoint of two or more sets, meaning having nothing in common. It can also be used as a verb meaning to disturb the organization of.

Comment: I do want to mean that 2 things have nothing in common. Actually I'm using it to mean that two geometric shapes don't intersect, so I wonder if either _disjointed_ or _disjointedness_ would be improper in my case since I don't want to mean some order is disturbed

Comment: According to Thesaurus.com Divide is a synonym of intersect and an synonym of that is disjoin which is a verb that means to become seperated. From what you have said, and what I have read, two things can be Disjoint from one another.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't say clear. My ultimate goal is to find a noun to express the meaning of two shapes not intersecting. Do you think _disjointedness_ is proper or any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/54648) gives the noun *disjoint* as an obsolete word meaning *A disjointed or out-of-joint condition; a position of perplexity or difficulty; a dilemma, ‘fix’.*  The adjective *disjointed* is given with these three definitions:

> 1. Separated joint from joint; disjoined, separated; disconnected.
> 2. Consisting of separated or ill-connected parts; disconnected.
> 3. Of words or a discourse: Without proper connection or sequence; disconnected; incoherent.

Answer (score 0):

As an American English speaker, I would understand if you told me, "these two figures are non-intersecting."  You could also tell me they are not connected or independent of one another. To say they are disjointed implies to me that for each figure. The angles are 'akimbo' or poorly connected/structured.  To say that anything is 'disjoint' sounds very odd to me, but it sounds like this fits among mathematicians.